# How to resize the images without disturbing the aspect ratio

Tags: c#, wpf, image, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I am working on `Windows 8 Phone app`, I have some images displaying in my app, the images which I have are very big with good quality, now in my app I need to resize the image without disturbing the aspect ratio.

I have searched for it and couldnt find a suitable soultion.

How to achieve this?

Here is my code in .CS file.

```
string imageName= "path to folder" + name + ".png";
BitmapImage bmp = new BitmapImage(new Uri(imageName, UriKind.Relative));
Image.Source = bmp;
```

**EDIT**

More info: Currently i am displaying images in my List Box, so the images are looking very big, so i want to decrease it to lower size without affecting the aspect ratio of the image.

Comment: What are you doing with the resized images?  Is the intent, just to show them at a smaller size on the screen?  If so, there is no need to generate another image.

Comment: @WaltRitscher yes , i am having images with big size but i want to show them in small size which looks good, i need to get the height and widht of image before rendred on the screen, if you have answers please post your answer

Answer (score 3):

If you want to load reduced image into memory then set `DecodePixelWidth` without setting 
`DecodePixelHeight` (or other way round)

```
BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
bitmapImage.DecodePixelWidth = 80; 
bitmapImage.UriSource = new Uri(imageName, UriKind.Relative);
```

**EDIT**

Or if you want to keep high resolution image in memory set size for `Image` control.

```
<Image ... Width="80"/>
```

`Stretch` property is set by default to `Uniform` which means:

> The content is resized to fit in the destination dimensions while it preserves its native aspect ratio.

Comment: Can you please explain how will it not affect the quality of the image here, i am new to windows 8 app developemnt

Comment: So do you want to reduce it for view only and keep high resolution image in memory or keep it reduced in memory?

Comment: Keeping aspect ratio is something different then keeping the quality. Do you want to keep high resolution image in memory and reduce it for view (keeping aspect ratio) or reduce its size in memory keeping aspect ration.

Comment: Ok, in that case the image which is big is already present in the app in some folder, so now i just need to decrease the size of the image that is big and display ,but provided the image should not be blured

Comment: I tried your solution but the images are looking blurred

Comment: And what happens if you set maximum size for `Image` control as `Stretch="Uniform"` by default aspect ratio will be maintained

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47506/discussion-between-goofy-and-dkozl)

Answer (score 1):

This should do:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int _newWidth = 60; //the new width is set, the height will be calculated

        var originalImage = Bitmap.FromFile(@"C:\temp\source.png");

        float factor = originalImage.Width / (float)_newWidth;
        int newHeight = (int)(originalImage.Height / factor);

        Bitmap resizedImage = ResizeBitmap(originalImage, _newWidth, newHeight);

        resizedImage.Save(@"c:\temp\target.png");
    }

    private static Bitmap ResizeBitmap(Image b, int nWidth, int nHeight)
    {
        Bitmap result = new Bitmap(nWidth, nHeight);
        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(result))
            g.DrawImage(b, 0, 0, nWidth, nHeight);
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Can you please explain how will it not affect the quality of the image here, i am new to windows 8 app developemnt

Comment: looks like you are saving the image in C drive : here resizedImage.Save(@"c:\temp\target.png"); , but as i have mentioned here i am working on windows 8 phone app developemnt

Comment: Not sure about windows phone 8, but i guess to load it would be Bitmap.FromStream and to save resizedImage.Save(stream)

Comment: So this will not work for Windows Phone 8 apps right ?

Comment: I guess after your edit, the answer of har07 will better

Comment: Graphics.FromImage is not available on Windows Phone

Answer (score 1):

If you want to reduce image size proportionally on display, try to play with Image control's `Stretch` property as demonstrated and explained very well in [this blog post](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Using-the-Image-control-in-Silverlight-2-Beta-1.aspx).

```
<Image x:Name="Image" Stretch="UniformToFill"></Image>
```

Answer (score 0):

The size of an image element is influenced by its containing panel,  but this should work in any panel.

```
<Grid>
    <Image Source='flower.png' Width='120' Stretch='Uniform'/>
  </Grid>
```